# Using rvest to return descendants of a table

Tags: html, r, xpath, rvest

I am having trouble figuring out why the following code isn't returning the information specified by the `xpath`.

I am trying to select the count data  found in the 'Core Questions' section of the page. I wanted to get it working for the table of the first question and then intended to extend it to do the same thing for each question/table on the page. Unfortunately I can get it to pull down the section of the table I am interested in. I imagine the answer involves specifying the children of the < tr > node I am interested in, i.e. multiple < td > tags, but my attempts to do this continue to fail. Would anyone be able to help me specify the part of the table I am interested in? (Bonus points if it can be done for all ten tables on the page!)

```
 library(rvest)

 detailed <- html("https://www.deakin.edu.au/evaluate/results/old/detail-rep.php?schedule_select=1301&faculty_select=01&school_select=0104&unit_select=MIS202&location_select=B")

 q1 <- detailed %>%
 html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="main"]/div/div/form/fieldset[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]') %>%
 html_table(header = TRUE, fill=TRUE)
```

When I go to the ancestor table it pulls down the information but it is extremely messy and difficult to interpret. When I try to specify elements within this table I am unable to extract info. Is anyone able to explain to me why the descendants of `table[1]` are not being extracted? Here is the code to pull down `table[1]`:

```
 q1 <- detailed %>%
 html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="main"]/div/div/form/fieldset[2]/table[1]') %>%
 html_table(header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: What exactly is the desired output here? The `html_table` function assumes you are passing in a `table` node. If you start selecting elements deeper in the table, it's not going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this get you where you need to be?

```
allqs <- detailed %>%
  html_nodes(css = ".result center") %>%
  html_text()


t(matrix(as.numeric(allqs), 5, 10, dimnames = list(c("Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"), 
                                    paste0("Q", 1:10))))
```

Which gives:

```
    Strongly Disagree Disagree Neutral Agree Strongly Agree
Q1                  0        4       4     9              1
Q2                  1        2       2    11              2
Q3                  0        0       2    11              5
Q4                  1        3       2     9              3
Q5                  0        3       4    10              1
Q6                  0        1       5     7              2
Q7                  0        3       6     6              3
Q8                  1        0       2     7              8
Q9                  0        0       5     7              5
Q10                 0        1       4     7              5
```

Comment: That works great, thanks @JayBlack. What would you say is the best way to learn what to specify in the html_nodes() function? I was trying xpath but you have used css, what indicates that `css` is the way to go? My biggest problem is probably that I don't have any html experience... Thanks again

Comment: If you haven't already, read the following vignette in the rvest documentation - it greatly simplifies the process of selecting the correct tags for data scraping.  http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/vignettes/selectorgadget.html